# Fitbit.Net 2.2 Activity log

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fitbit

My project is MVC 5, I am using Fitbit.Net library to access user Fitbit's data.  Is there a way to get the activity name and duration?

I tried

```
 var stats = await fitbitClient.GetDayActivityAsync(DateTime.Today, null);
```

I get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the logged activity was not one of the common Fitbit activities so it did not show up.  However, if the activity is a common, it works.

[image]